# PySpark Keep only Year and Month in Date

Tags: dataframe, date, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe with a column `date_key` with Datetype. The problem is I want to create another column with only `yyyy-mm`part of the `date_key`, but still keep it date type. I tried `(to_date(df[date_key],'YYYY-MM')` which does not work. Also tried `date_format(df[date_key] , 'YYYY-MM')`but the result is string rather than date type. Could someone please help? Many thanks. The result I need to get is in the format of `2020-09`, with no date or timestamp after.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `date_trunc` to reduce the precision of a timestamp:

```
df = spark.createDataFrame([['2020-09-30'], ['2020-11-11']], ['date'])\
      .select(to_date(col('date'), 'yyyy-MM-dd').alias('date_key'))
df.show()
```

```
+----------+
|  date_key|
+----------+
|2020-09-30|
|2020-11-11|
+----------+
```

Then truncate:

```
df.select(f.date_trunc('mm', col('date_key'))).show()
```

```
+------------------------+
|date_trunc(mm, date_key)|
+------------------------+
|     2020-09-01 00:00:00|
|     2020-11-01 00:00:00|
+------------------------+
```

`date_trunc` will retain the precision up to the specified format, `mm` in this case meaning month.

Comment: Thanks but the result I need to get is `2020-09` without the `01`  date part, it's not about the precision

Comment: @user3735871 You're mixing up the actual timestamp and what it looks like when printed. `"2020-09"` can be a string representation for `2020-09-01 00:00:00` or for `2020-09-01` or for `2020-09-01 00:00:00.000`, all of which are date or timestamp values. There is no default format that prints `2020-09`. But the value output by my code above is `2020-09` but as date/time types, which is what you were looking for.

Comment: Of course you can use `date_format(df['date_key'],'yyyy-MM')`, as you did and said it yourself. But that yields a string, not a timestamp.